# Get my posts from facebook wall

Tags: c#, facebook

I am trying to get posts from my facebook profile.
I have the following code:

```
 FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient("token");
 dynamic result = fbClient.Get("me/feed");
```

Result is empty, but I have two posts. I have tried to test online via Graph API Explorer. And, in the debug mode I get one warning:

> The field 'posts' is only accessible on the User object after the user grants the 'user_posts' permission.

But, I have added `user_posts` permission in the App Center Permission dialog.

[image: App center permission]

Where is a problem?

Another question. My application need to get posts from my page only. Do I have to make facebook application as public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about the App Center and implement a proper Login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

You need to authorize the user with `user_posts` before you can get his posts.